# GATT-like procotol over TCP

Tags: tcp, server, properties, gatt, characteristics

I am searching for a protocol on top of TCP/IP that behaves like BLE GATT.
The server should announce which characteristics/properties it offers and the client can read/write/subscribe to them.

Also, it should be very lightweight, since it needs to run on two MCUs connected directly to each other.

Is there anything in that direction?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.  Did you find anything?

Comment: nope, can't even remember what project that was for. Currently, MQTT with homie suffices for most cases. Homie may be a bit too much overhead though if you don't need auto discovery...